# Does Microsoft BOT Framework allows to develop interactive UIs?

Tags: c#, botframework, cortana

I have a requirement to implement some interactive UIs using Microsoft Bot Framework for Cortana Channel but I have not found any way to implement this. I want to apply styles on buttons and importantly use graphs & charts (like web dashboard) on Cortana.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Charts using c# Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620871/how-to-create-charts-using-c-sharp-bot-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to apply styles on buttons and importantly use graphs & charts (like web dashboard) on Cortana.

A bot is an web application service which works on server side, `BotFramework` provides channels which are the connection between bot and native apps such as Skype and here Cortana. The UI part is rendered in each native app, I can't find a way to customize the style for Cortana app. However, [AdaptiveCards](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/AdaptiveCard.html) provides several simple properties for styling, for more information, you can refer to the official sample: [cards-AdaptiveCards](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-AdaptiveCards).

For the question of interactive graphs & charts, AFAIK, it is not currently supported. What we can do for now, is to render the chart to an image and display this image in `HeroCard` or `AdaptiveCard`, but this workaround will make the chart lose its interactivity. You can refer to my last answer in the thread [How to create Charts using c# Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620871/how-to-create-charts-using-c-sharp-bot-framework)

Comment: Thanks @Grace Feng, We might use the HeroCard to show an image on Cortana because AdaptiveCards are not supported by Cortana. Check from the following link:
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=SigninCard&e=example1

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can use `Hero card, adaptive cards, thumbnail cards, receipt cards etc`.

**below is the example for your reference.**

public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

```
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();

        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        reply.Attachments = GetCardsAttachments();

        await context.PostAsync(reply);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments()
    {
        return new List<Attachment>()
        {
            GetHeroCard(
                "Add a webpage",
                "",
                "",
                new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Add a webpage", value: "Add a webpage")),
            GetHeroCard(
                "delete a webpage",
                "",
                "",
                new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "delete a webpage", value: "delete a webpage")),
            GetHeroCard(
                "Display help",
                "",
                "",
                new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Display help", value: "Display help")),
            GetHeroCard(
                "etc",
                "",
                "",
                new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "etc", value: "etc")),

        };
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, string subtitle, string text, CardImage cardImage, CardAction cardAction)
    {
        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Subtitle = subtitle,
            Text = text,
            Images = new List<CardImage>() { cardImage },
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { cardAction },
        };

        return heroCard.ToAttachment();
    }
```

**Screen shot for your reference**
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Manoj currently adaptive cards are not allowed for Cortana Channel. Yes I can use the Hero Cards that are not enough to fullfill my requirements as I want to show the interactive graphs and UIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize Web chat itself following [this guideline](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/). As far as charts and graphs, Adaptive cards would be your best bet, but as mentioned above it's not currently supported.